# Merge columns and convert to utc timezone

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python pandas. I have 3 columns as below. Date and time column should be merged to one column called datetime and converted into UTC time zone. Also, both date and time column should be dropped after datetime column is created.

```
date       Seq  time
1/15/2018   1   0:00
1/15/2018   2   0:01
1/15/2018   3   0:02
1/15/2018   4   0:03
1/15/2018   5   0:04
1/15/2018   6   0:05
1/15/2018   7   0:06
1/15/2018   8   0:07
1/15/2018   9   0:08
1/15/2018   10  0:09
1/15/2018   11  0:10
1/15/2018   12  0:11
1/15/2018   13  0:12
```

I tried below code but I see that datetime is in epoch timestamp.

```
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + " " + df['time'] + ":00"
logging.info(df)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00"))
```

Can some one please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think assign to column is not necessary, only join and convert by [`dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html), last remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time']).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
df = df.drop(['date','time'], axis=1)
print (df)
    Seq                  datetime
0     1 2018-01-15 00:00:00+00:00
1     2 2018-01-15 00:01:00+00:00
2     3 2018-01-15 00:02:00+00:00
3     4 2018-01-15 00:03:00+00:00
4     5 2018-01-15 00:04:00+00:00
5     6 2018-01-15 00:05:00+00:00
6     7 2018-01-15 00:06:00+00:00
7     8 2018-01-15 00:07:00+00:00
8     9 2018-01-15 00:08:00+00:00
9    10 2018-01-15 00:09:00+00:00
10   11 2018-01-15 00:10:00+00:00
11   12 2018-01-15 00:11:00+00:00
12   13 2018-01-15 00:12:00+00:00
```

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: One more question if you can suggest, when I convert the dataframe to json, the timestamp is getting converted into epoch time i.e. before conversion to json the values is as expected i.e. `2018-01-15 00:00:00+00:00` but after json conversion its converted to epoch time, example - `"datetime":1516147200000`

Comment: I think you can check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#id1), so `date_format='iso'` should help.

Comment: Thank you, it helped as well !!